# Can't create free subscription

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, subscriptions

I try to download my app in the category "Magazines & Newspapers". My app also uses Newsstand. But when I try to publish the application, iTunes Connect tells me to create a auto-renewable or a free subscription. Free subscription suits me. The problem is that when I create a In-App purchase is not an option to create a free. I also have no way to put a price tag - 0 (free) for auto-renewable subscription. Have any ideas to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free subscription is deprecated. See: [WWDC 2016 - Session 301](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/301/)